# Countable set notations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there is a difference between the following notations?

$$
\theta = \{x_i, y_i\}_{i=1}^N
$$

and

$$
\theta = \cup_{i=1}^N \{x_i, y_i\}
$$

If not, is there a preference for one over another?

Edit:

What I'm trying to express is actually the nested version of this, if this notation is correct,

$$
\theta = \{\{x_{t,i}, y_{t,i}\}_{i=1}^N\}_{t=1}^T
$$

The result should be a "list of tuples" (in computer science speak) of length $N \times T$. Each element of the list is a pair of $(x, y)$.

Comment: The first can be recognized as a (finite) sequence of sets. The second can be recognized as a set. They are not the same concepts so it makes no sense to speak of preference.

Comment: What I'm trying to express is "list of tuples" in computer science language. Which, from your answer, sounds like it's the former?

Comment: Yes, the former. However there is a difference between $(a,b)$ and $\{a,b\}$. The first is an ordered pair (also named as "tuple") and the second an unordered pair. I suspect that for your situation $(a,b)$ should be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the fist notation as the family of sets $\{x_i, y_i\}$, indexed by $i$, ranging from $1$ to $N$.

The second notation denotes the union of these sets, which is something different.

Answer to your EDIT. Yes, the same kind of notation is used for $n \times m$ matrices: $(a_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i \leqslant, 1 \leqslant j \leqslant m}$. However, your comment suggest that you are considering ordered pairs (or 2-uples), but the notation $\{x_{t,i}, y_{t,i}\}$ refers to a set rather than an ordered pair. If you want an ordered pair, the notation $(x_{t,i}, y_{t,i})$ would be more appropriate.

Comment: I've edited the question to add what I'm actually trying to express. Sounds like it should be the former?

Comment: Thanks. Just confirming that it's $\theta = {(x_{t,i}, y_{t,i})_{i=1}^N}_{t=1}^T$?